# Network Volumes Keep Changing Names OSX

Tags: macos, network-shares

It seems everytime I reconnect network volumes, my drives cycle through names like /Volumes/user, /Volumes/user~1, /Volumes/user~2

Is there any way to stop this? I just want the name of a network volume to stay the same so that I don't have to keep re-mapping things when I reconnect the drive.